# Automated Actions - Mouse Clicks Based on Text Displayed

Tags: facebook, mouse, bots

I am looking for a way to automate mouse clicks based on display text on screen.

The main function is the following: 
- When bot detects "Hello!" on screen of Facebook Messenger, it clicks to open conversation. Then it reads the message (messages are always the same) and depending on the messages received it clicks on Saved Replies and sends the correct message.

For example:
Bot detects "hello!" it clicks and opens the conversation. Then bot reads "Amazing Offer 20% off" so it goes to Saved Replies and sends the correct message according to that offer.

*Saved replies is a canned message function that facebook for business messages offers as a function. So basically all I need is a bot that can automate clicks and detect text on screen. It will be run from a PC using Windows.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just use the Facebook API. That way you don't need to read what is on the screen

Comment: Problem is I dont want a chat bot. All I want is automating a series of clicks depending on the information on the screen. Is that possible also with API?

Answer (score 0):

There are three options.

1) **Use the Facebook API**.
Facebook have spent time and effort to build a system in which developers can interact with their products. Here is a link: https://messengerplatform.fb.com

Options that might be against their policies and will get your account blocked (or worse):

2) **Chrome Extension**.
Through a Chrome extension, you have the ability to scan the DOM every few seconds and interact with the elements.
This needs to be maintained as Facebook might change element positions, ids or classes. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

3) **PhantomJs**.
This is a headless browser which you can run and interact with the DOM elements. This also needs to be maintained as the DOM may change at any time.
http://phantomjs.org/page-automation.html